# How to query xml of this structure?

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <root>
    <level1>
        <item id="1" date="" name="" >
        <item id="2" date="" name="" >
        <item id="3" date="" name="" >
        <item id="4" date="" name="" >
        <item id="5" date="" name="" >
    </level1>
 </root>
```

I have an xml structure like the one above.

I used

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/level1");
```

If I used xmlnodelist as above, how can I specifically only get the element with id="3"?

or more useful if I could store all elements inside  as elements in xnlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//level1/item[@id='3']");
```

and if you want to use [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); // XDocument.Load(filename)
var items = xDoc.Descendants("level1")
                .First()
                .Elements("item")
                .Select(item => new { 
                                    ID = item.Attribute("id").Value, 
                                    Name = item.Attribute("name").Value 
                                })
                .ToList();
```

You can even combine XPath and Linq2Xml

```
var item2 = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//level1/item")
                .Select(item => new { 
                                    ID = item.Attribute("id").Value, 
                                    Name = item.Attribute("name").Value 
                                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks L.B.! How can I query to get all elements inside level1 though?

Comment: Thanks L.B for the extra Linq to Xml solution. I think I like that Linq to Xml more!

Answer (score 2):

besides the great answer from @L.B I also use Linq, personally I think is a lot more readable:

```
xdoc.Element("level1")
    .Descendants("item")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "3").First();
```

but it all depends on your style ;)